# Advertisement on tag unity-container seems to be incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

The sponsored link on [unity-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-container) (a Dependency Injection-related term) points to a question of the Unity 3D Engine.

This seems to be incorrect.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, thanks for pointing this out. We've spoken to the advertiser and have shifted this tag sponsorship to the more appropriate unity3d tag. (I'm an Ad Ops campaign manager at Stack Overflow)